# For what $\alpha$ is the Entropy $H=(EVN)^{\alpha}$ physically reasonable?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

> Consider a thermodynamical system with entropy $H(E,V,N)=(EVN)^{\alpha}$ and $\alpha>0$. Determine temperature, pressure, chemical potential and for which $\alpha$ these are physically reasonable.

Using $$\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial E},\quad\frac{p}{T}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial V},\text{ and }\ \frac{\mu}{T}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial N}$$ I got to

\begin{aligned}
T&=\frac{E^{1-\alpha}}{(VN)^\alpha \alpha}\\[1em]
p&=\frac{E}{V}\\[1em]
\mu&=-\frac{E}{N}
\end{aligned}

Since we often neglect $k_B$ I assume that the first equation should actually be $k_B T=\frac{E^{1-\alpha}}{(VN)^\alpha \alpha}$. Looking at the units one would then get $J=\frac{J^{1-\alpha}}{m^{3\alpha}}$ but this would imply $\alpha=0$ what is not allowed in this problem.

Is the exercise wrong or am I making a mistake here?

Comment: Entropy is not often labeled $H$. Out of curiosity, in which context is this being used?

Comment: In my statistical physics & thermodynamics course we started with information theory in which we called entropy H, when moving to physics we just kept it this way. We only used S when specificly talking about Shannon entropy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The units are a minor problem which could be cured by a single multiplicative constant (or using non-standard units for entropy).

The key issue is whether the proposed formula obeys the basic requests physics makes on entropy of any thermodynamic system at a stable equilibrium:

1. it should be a strictly monotonic increasing function of energy (otherwise absolute temperature would be negative);
2. it should be a continuous function  and should have   left and right directional derivatives almost everywhere (this is a consequence of the following requiement 4, but it is convenient to check it independently);
3. it should be a homogeneous function of degree $1$ of its extensive variables (it is a consequence of of continuity and additivity of entropy;
4. entropy per particle (or per volume) should be a concave function of its extensive variables (in order to have homogeneous one-phase equilibria, where strictly concave, or two-phase phase coexistence, where the inequality for concavity becomes an equality);
5. for any finite $V$ and $N$, at the state  such that $\left( \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{E}} \right)^{-1}_{V,N}=0$ we should have $H=0$ (third principle of thermodynamics).

   Now, the proposed function:

   - satisfies condition $1$ in its domain of positive $E$, since $\alpha \gt 0$ by hypothesis;
   - it is continuous and differentiable in its whole domain;
   - it is a homogeneous function of degree $1$ provided $\alpha=\frac13$;
   - for such a value of $\alpha$, $H/N$ is a strictly concave function;
   - for $\alpha=\frac13$ and  any finite $N$ and $V$, the state at which $\left( \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{E}} \right)^{-1}_{V,N}=0$ is the state at $E=0$. In such a state $H=0$.

In conclusion, only for $\alpha=\frac13$ the above formula may represent an acceptable entropy function for a thermodynamic system.

Comment: On condition 1: aren't there systems with negative absolute temperature in real life (e.g. population inversions in lasing gases)?

Comment: @probably_someone You are right. There are systems with negative absolute temperature. However, the conditions for having negative temperature systems are restrictive and not generic. In particular, the energy should have both a lower and an upper bound with entropy vanishing at the two extrema. I am not aware of any negative temperature fluid system (i.e. characterized by $E,V,N$ as state variables). The kinetic energy term of the Hamiltonian allows unlimited positive energies. More important for the present question, negative temperatures were excluded by the requirement $\alpha>0$

Answer (score 2):

As the problem stands at the moment, the units really don't make sense no matter what.

If the entropy is really defined as $H=(EVN)^{\alpha}$, then its units are $(\text{J}\cdot\text{L})^{\alpha}$. Entropy has units of $\text{J}/\text{K}$. There is no value of $\alpha$ that will make these units match up.

This problem could be fixed by setting

$$H=H_0\left(\frac{EVN}{C}\right)^\alpha$$

where $H_0$ is a constant that has units of entropy and $C$ is a constant that has units of $\text{J}\cdot\text{L}$. This way the base of the exponent is dimensionless, as it should be, and the expression has the proper units of entropy. In that case, $\alpha$ is constrained mainly by the fact that temperature should not go to infinity as energy goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, with it $T=E^{1-\alpha}\frac{1}{\alpha H_0} (\frac{C}{NV})^{\alpha}$ and if $\alpha \in(0,1)$ it follows that $T \rightarrow 0$ for $E \rightarrow 0$ what makes sense. So the answer is an interval instead of one exact value?

Comment: @Kekks It's likely that $\alpha$ can take any value in some range, yes.